# how to open a modal after 3 sec?

Tags: php, html, css

code:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function()
     {
       setInterval(function() 
         {
           $('#contact').modal();
         }, 3000);
     });
</script>
```

html code:

```
<a href="#contact"><h4><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Contact Us</h4></a>
<div id="contact" class="modalDialog">
<div> 
  <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
    <h2>Thanks For Visiting Us</h2>
    <form method="post">
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
      <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Your Phone">
      <input type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter Your Message">
      <input name="captcha_code" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter the code">
      <img src="captcha.php" id="capImage"/>
      <br/>Can't read the image? click here to  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:$('#capImage').attr('src','captcha.php');">refresh</a>.
      <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Submit" placeholder="Enter Your Message" >
  </form>
</div>
```

I want when page is load after 3 sec modal will open. Here, I m using setinterval method for open modal after 3 sec but it can't. So, How can I open modal after 3 second using setinterval method ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing be sure that you have included bootstrap.min.js

Change in this html

```
    id="contact" class="modalDialog"
```

to

```
    id="contact" class="modal"
```

When you use .modal() function, the main class of that model should be "modal".
Your script function is working fine, just change the class.

Answer (score 0):

use setTimeout function

```
$(window).on('load', function($) {
    setTimeout(function(){
   $('#contact').modal();
 }, 3000);
  })
```

Comment: sorry suresh I m editing in my question please read it again and then answer me.